# Error SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB

Tags: php

Estoy intentando insertar en mi base de datos un registro, este módulo fucionaba a la perfección y hoy que he dicidido probarlo y aparece el siguiente error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.000.00, 2, 1, '1' ...' at line 12

he chequeado el manual y no he conseguido dar con el error.
La línea 12 es donde se encuentra el select que al parecer es donde se encuentra el error

```
<?php 

session_start();
include "./php/conexion.php";

if(!isset($_SESSION['datos_logueo'])){
    header("Location: login.php?error=Para poder pagar su plan debe iniciar sesión o registrarse");
 
}
$idp=$_GET['id_plan'];
if( isset($_GET['id_plan'])){
$resultado = $conexion ->query("select * from planes where id_plan=".$_GET['id_plan'])or die($conexion -> error);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0 ){
      $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

      $duracion = $fila[5];
      $arreglousuario = $_SESSION['datos_logueo'];
      $id = $arreglousuario['id_usuario'];
      
        if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['documento']) 
        && isset($_POST['banco']) && isset($_POST['numero_cuenta']) && isset($_POST['referencia'])
        && isset($_POST['monto'])) {

            #Creamos objeto con la fecha actual
            $fecha = new DateTime();
            $fecha_venc = new DateTime();
            $fecha_venc->modify( sprintf( '%+d months', intval( $duracion ) ) );
            
            $carpeta="./imagenes/capturaspagos/"; 
            $nombre= $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
            
            //imagen.algo.jpg
            $temp= explode( '.' ,$nombre);
            $extension= end($temp);
        
            $nombrefinal = time().'.'.$extension;
            if(!empty($_FILES['imagen']['name'])){  
            if(mime_content_type($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) =='image/png' || mime_content_type($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])=='image/jpeg'){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpeta.$nombrefinal)){ 
            $sql1 = $conexion ->query ("insert into pagos
            (nombre,documento,banco,numero_cuenta,referencia,fecha_pago,fecha_vencimiento,monto,imagen,
            id_usuario,id_plan,id_estatus) values
            ( 
            '".$_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['apellido']."',
             ".$_POST['documento'].",
            '".$_POST['banco']."',
            ".$_POST['numero_cuenta'].",
            ".$_POST['referencia'].",
            '{$fecha->format('YmdHis')}',
            '{$fecha_venc->format('YmdHis')}',
            ".$_POST['monto'].",
            '$nombrefinal',
            $id,
            $idp,
            '1'
            
          )
            ")or die ($conexion->error);
            header("Location: planes.php?success");         
        //SI SE REALIZA LA SUBIDA REALIZAS EL INSERT      
      }else{
        header("Location: planes.php?error=No se pudo subir la imagen"); 
       }
  
    }else{
     
        header("Location: planes.php?error=Por favor subir imagen jpg o png");  
      
  } 

}
  
  else{
               
            $sql2 = $conexion ->query ("insert into pagos
            (nombre,documento,banco,numero_cuenta,referencia,fecha_pago,fecha_vencimiento,monto,
            id_usuario,id_plan,id_estatus) values
            ( 
            '".$_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['apellido']."',
             ".$_POST['documento'].",
            '".$_POST['banco']."',
            ".$_POST['numero_cuenta'].",
            ".$_POST['referencia'].",
            '{$fecha->format('YmdHis')}',
            '{$fecha_venc->format('YmdHis')}',
            ".$_POST['monto'].",
            $id,
            $idp,
            '1'
            
          )
            ")or die ($conexion->error);
            header("Location: planes.php?success");     
    
        }   
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudar

Comment: Sería interesante que todo el select lo metieras en una variable e hicieses un print para ver si realmente contiene lo que quiere ejecutar.

Comment: Está en la variable $resultado

Comment: ¿Y se ve bien si la muestras? ¿con las comillas bien puestas, etc.? ¿has probado a ejecutarlo directamente en la línea de comandos de la base de datos?

Comment: De hecho si, con ese select abajo de ese módulo en el html traigo datos de esa consulta y vienen perfectos

Comment: Descubrí el problema está en el monto, estoy guadando decimales por eso falla

Answer (score 0):

¿Has validado si el $_GET['id_plan'] está almacenando el valor que requieres?

Si quieres probar de una forma directa si tu consulta tiene algún detalle puedes imprimirla y en la línea siguiente colocar un **die()** para que no siga la ejecución, luego copias el **select** impreso y lo colocas en la consola de **MariaDB** para validar si te devuelve algo, si gustas puedes poner el resultado aquí para validar cómo se está construyendo la consulta.

Debería salir algo semejante a esto si usas var_dump para exponerla:

string(36) "select * from planes where id_plan=1"

Comment: Hola Miguel Feliz Año nuevo, gracias por responder el id_plan si está trayendo el valor que requiero, el problema está en la variable "monto" que no se por que motivo me genera el error al intentar guardar decimales

Comment: Feliz año para ti también!!, ¿Puedes validar el tipo de dato que posee el campo que almacena el valor de "monto" en la base de datos? si el tipo de datos que tienes ahí no coincide con el tipo de datos que envías puede mandar ese error (int en vez de float por ejemplo).  

Un saludo